# Bash Scripting - User Input a Command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Very easy question but I really can't find this when I Google. Sorry!
I'm trying to write a script that runs a user's command that he or she enters but I can't run the command that the user enters.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter a Command: "
read $COMMAND
echo "Output: $COMMAND"  # I can't figure how to implement and print the command
```

Enter a Command: ls
Output: folder1 folder2 folder3 test.txt)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to delete the dollar sign from the read command

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a Command: "
read COMMAND
echo "Output: $COMMAND"
```

Happy scripting!, please don't forget to marked as answered ;)

Comment: As a general rule, in shell syntax you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* the value. So you don't use `$` when reading into a variable, assigning to it with `=`, etc.

Comment: You never use `$` to set the value of a variable. `read`, however, takes the *name* of a variable as its argument, which can be the result of a parameter expansion. `COMMAND=foo; read $COMMAND` is equivalent to `read foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` to execute a command from a variable.

Also, you don't put `$` before the variable name in the `read` command. That's only used when you want to get the variable's value.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter a Command: "
read COMMAND
echo Output:
eval "$COMMAND"
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/wBpeLB)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but nothing output'd to my screen:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo -e "Command: "
read $COMMAND
eval "$COMMAND"

Comment: `read $COMMAND` should be `read COMMAND`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This answered my question:

#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter a Command: "
read COMMAND
echo Output:
eval "$COMMAND"